# How to query first and last name in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to have a fairly intelligent search box for finding objects by a person's name.  In linq, it would look something like this:

```
users = users.Where(m => m.FirstName.Contains(query) || m.LastName.Contains(query) || (m.FirstName + " " + m.LastName).Contains(query) || (m.LastName + " " + m.FirstName).Contains(query) || (m.LastName + ", " + m.FirstName).Contains(query));
```

But this seems like it might be a bad way to do things, and I'm really not sure how performance degrades with Linq.  Is this type of statement fine or is there a way to improve on this?

Comment: I just love this "religion" of doing everything using `Linq` no matter how stupid and shortsighted it is.
Your question is an excellent one and your query belongs to DB, not the linq.

Comment: Usually, if trying to create an "intelligent" search I would run a few routines to parse the input into a common format.  For example, detecting the usage of a comma would trigger a routine to split into first name and last name, then follow with a corresponding linq query.

Comment: You will need up to five indexes to run that query quickly, unless you have not-too-many records.

Comment: @Dusan And what would have changed if he had done the query in the DB? Unless he has five indexes, it will still require a full table scan.

Comment: The is really a full-text search type of problem.

Comment: As you do (m.FirstName + " " + m.LastName).Contains(query) I don't see the point to compare each one of them individually for matching.

Comment: Good points all, I've removed the individual comparisons and changed to `StartsWith` and I'm reading up on full-text search from the link given by Trent, FTS is new to me

Answer (score 3):

EF is just going to convert the LINQ query to SQL and execute the SQL statement against the database.  Your query above will translate to a where clause with an OR.  Each `contains()` will translate to a `like` in SQL.  So, you'll get something like:

```
select *
from users
where FirstName like '%query%'
or LastName like '%query%'
```

As long as that resulting query performs okay, you should be fine.

If it doesn't perform well, you could look at adding an index or maybe using a full-text search.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx